# Magento 2 Seo title product override not working

Tags: magento2, overrides, seo, title

I overrided the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View.php` adding this code

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set($title . '- suffix');

    return $this;
}
```

And added the 
`<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" type="Indetach\Catalog\Block\Product\View" />`

But it's not working....

Comment: run di:compil command

Comment: I did it, but the seo title is still the same on the product page...

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use plug in for Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View as describe below to override Product View Page SEO title.

I assume you are using a custom module named "Company_MyModule".

**step 1:**

Create **di.xml** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/etc/frontend/***

**File** : *YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/etc/frontend/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View">
        <plugin name="CompanyModuleProductViewHelperData" type="Company\MyModule\Plugin\ProductPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>  
</config>
```

**step 2:**

Create **ProductPlugin.php** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/Plugin/***

**File** : *YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/Plugin/ProductPlugin.php*

```
<?php

namespace Company\MyModule\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View as ProductViewHelper;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page as ResultPage;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;

class ProductPlugin
{


        public function beforeInitProductLayout(
        ProductViewHelper $subject,
        $resultPage,
        $product,
        $params
    ) {


        if ($resultPage instanceof ResultPage  ) {
             $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set('YOUR PRODUCT SEO TITLE');
        }
        return [
            $resultPage,
            $product,
            $params
        ];
    }  


}
```

**Step 3:** Run DI compile

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it out, the product still appears, but the seo title and the page title now is "404 error", the method to override is "preparePageMetadata" but there's no way to do that cause it's private....

Comment: Please try to override initProductLayout ( not preparePageMetadata) of the class Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View (as per my answer). I successfully override SEO Title by using before Plugin for public method initProductLayout. Thank you

Comment: Is your magento version 2.3? I can't override it, I did it but when I get to the product page, the product is going to load but the seo title and the page title show 404 error

Comment: No. My Magento version is not 2.3 but I can test the code in M 2.3  and let to know.

Comment: My bad, it doesn't show the 404 error but the seo title still not changing...

Comment: What is the final solution???